# Помощь с включением файлов в проект

Tags: python

Доброго времени суток!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, которая состоит в том, что я не знаю как включить нужные мне модули в мой проект. Получается это сделать только, если указываю полный путь до папки, где лежат модули:

[image: клик]

Так вот, как мне сделать так, чтобы не указывать путь до папки, начиная от имени диска (в моём случает от "W:.."), а только путь от файла, где я использую модули?

[image: клик]

Красным кружком выделен использующий файл, а стрелочкой - папка, где лежат мои модули.

P.S. прошу прощения за кривое объяснение.
P.S.S. Кто-нибудь знает способ, чтобы то же самое проделать с либой Pygame? Просто, там тоже нужно включать файлы в проект, а я умею только через полное имя файла вот так `os.path.join(PATH_TO_FILE , FILE_NAME.expansion)`.

Спасибо за то, что уделили мне своё время.

Comment: в сторону: используйте raw strings: `r'C:\...'` для путей Windows, иначе `\t`, `\U...` как специальные последовательности могут распознаться.

Comment: старайтесь помещать текст в вопрос в виде текста, а не картинки, чтобы облегчить поиск этого вопроса для людей с похожей проблемой  (см. [цели сайта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4181/23044))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Модули, которые не являются частью вашего проекта, такие как `pygame` следует устанавливать (к примеру, с помощью `pip install pygame`).  Это автоматически помещает pygame (среди прочего) в директорию из `sys.path` по умолчанию (`site.getsitepackages()`).

Модули, которые являются часть проекта, следует в пакет объединить. Структура:

```
Ваш проект/
  README.rst
  setup.py
  ваш_пакет/
    __init__.py  # отмечаем как пакет
    __main__.py  # основной скрипт
    модуль.py
    подчинённый_пакет/
      __init__.py
      ещё_модуль.py
      итд.py
```

`ещё_модуль` можно проимпортировать из `__main__.py`:

```
from ваш_пакет.подчинённый_пакет import ещё_модуль
```

В такой структуре, запустить скрипт (`__main__.py`) вы можете, используя

```
C:\путь\Ваш проект> py -mваш_пакет
```

(Если хотите запускать не только из директории `Ваш проект`, то следует ваш пакет установить, к примеру, на время разработки командой:

```
C:\путь\Ваш проект> py -mpip install -e .
```

Полезно проглядеть https://packaging.python.org/

Чтобы руками каждый раз, начиная новый проект, одинаковую структуру, подходящую для вашего типа проектов не создавать, можно [cookiecutter использовать](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html#available-cookiecutters). Если вы знакомы с такими инструментами как `composer` (PHP), cargo (Rust),
 то попробуйте [poet](https://github.com/sdispater/poet).

Answer (score 1):

from Zenon.Modules.[имя скрипта без расширения] import [Названия импортируемых классов, функций через запятую]

Например:
from Zenon.Modules.Script2 import SomeMyClass

Аналогично будет(следуя от текущей папки):
from .Modules.Script2 import SomeMyClass

Comment: 1-  Zenon директория не обязана быть в pythonpath (импорт не будет работать) 2- импортирование скрипта может запустить код, который вы не ожидаете, если скрипт явно `if __main__` защиту не использует 3- относительные импорты (такие как `from .Modules ...` вообще не работают в скриптах) 4- без `__init__.py` импорты могут работать (namespace package), но это предназначено для пакетов, которые из нескольких мест собираются. Для обычных пакетов, следует `__init__.py` в директории создать, чтобы лишних сюрпризов не было откуда модули берутся.