# Как импортировать модули в Pyton 3.6.2? Не работает import, ошибка module not found error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Как импортировать модули в Python 3.6.2? Начал изучать python, в книге раздел про импорт модулей, вот пример: я создал текстовый файл с текстом `print(‘Hello module world!’)` и сохранил с названием module1.py. Файл я закинул в папку с питоном. Как сказано в книге, просто введя `import module1` питон импортирует содержимое файла, где бы на компе он не находился, либо его можно выполнить командой `python module1`.

Короче, способ не работает на версии 3.6.2, вводил и `module1` и `module1.py`, не находит файл, ни через вызов интерпретатора Python из командной строки, ни через IDLE. Ошибка `module not found error`, а при команде `python module1` — `syntax error`.

PATH на компе настроен. Поискал, пишут что эта фишка работала на python до версии 3.5, а с версии 3.6 способ изменили, вот только как на 3.6 импортировать я так и не нашёл ничего понятного.

```
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:57:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import module1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module1'
>>> import module1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module1'
>>> python module1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python module1
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> python module1.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python module1.py
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Насчёт `syntax error` поподробней, пожалуйста, что ещё тогда вам интерпретатор сказал?

Comment: SyntaxError: Invalid syntax

Comment: наверняка там ещё номер строчки был?

Comment: >>> python module1.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python module1.py
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Что у вас в первой строчке файла `module1.py` записано? Судя по вопросу там строчка `print('Hello module world!')`, а судя по ошибке что-то не то...

Comment: Первая строка файла,без пробелов,print('Hello module world!')

Comment: Наверно я какие-то глупые вопросы задаю и лучше бы кто-нибудь поопытней вам отвечал, но всё-таки: посмотрите, пожалуйста, в проводнике размер файла `module1.py` в байтах. И ещё проверьте, вокруг строки `Hello module world!` точно правильные кавычки стоят? Потому что в вопросе они какие-то странные.

Comment: @Евгений, вставьте код вашей программы прямо в вопрос, выделите его и нажмите кнопку `{}` редактора (или Ctrl-K). Иначе это будет гаданием на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Размер файла 28 байт,код добавил в вопрос,кавычки правильные,проверял просто в интерпретаторе введя print('hello module world'),вывело со сл строки hello module world.Меня больше интересует,почему не работает import,оно просто не находит файл или не видит его,и так с любым файлом,который я создаю,ничего не находит и не запускает командой python

Answer (score 2):

> **Q:** Как импортировать модули в Python 3.6.2?

Для ситуации в вопросе: *также как и на предыдущих версиях Питона*, вплоть до Питона 2. В Питон 3.6 вы получаете более специфичное исключение [ModuleNotFoundError](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#other-language-changes) вместо более общей ImportError, когда модуль не найден, но это никак не влияет на тот факт, что модуль не найден.

> Как сказано в книге, просто введя import module1 питон импортирует содержимое файла, где бы на компе он не находился,

Неверно. Вы не можете кинуть `module1.py` в любую папку и ожидать, что из откуда угодно из другой папки сможете проимпортировать модуль. Упрощая, `module1.py` ищется в одной из папок в [`sys.path` (pythonpath)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path), когда Питон встречает `import module1` конструкцию.

Директория с текущим скриптом автоматически добавляется в `sys.path`. Если вы просто `python` запустили (без скрипта), то текущая рабочая директория добавляется. См. [Текущая директория в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535318/23044).

> либо его можно выполнить командой python module1

Неверно.

1. Вы не должны пытаться `python.exe` из Питон REPL (уже запущенного Питона, там где вы видите `>>>`) выполнять. Вместо этого `python` команда с командной строчки запускается (cmd.exe, bash, etc).
2. Если `module1.py` в текущей папке лежит, то вы можете `python module1.py` команду выполнить (в командной строке — не в Питоне), чтобы как скрипт запустить этот модуль
3. Можно как `python -mmodule1` запустить, если папка с `module1.py` в `sys.path`.

> **Q:** Как сделать,что бы импорт файла работал из нужной мне папки?Когда мой файл "module1.py" находится в директории с питоном,то всё работает,я создал в директории с питоном папку "myworks" и переместил файл туда,и теперь питон его не видит,хотя я добавил эту папку в Path

Это зависит от того что вы понимаете под "импорт файла" (запустить как скрипт или импортировать из другого скрипта). Если как импортировать, то  посмотрите на `sys.path` список. Не нужно пытаться модули рядом с `python.exe` класть. Изменение `%PATH%` переменной никак на `sys.path` не влияет (это совершенно независимый набор директорий).

Чтобы с лексикой освоиться, посмотрите на связанные вопросы:

- [Как структурировать проект, чтобы запускать `setup.py` test из корневой папки проекта и `__main__.py` в субдериктории?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/623709/23044)
- [Помощь с включением файлов в проект](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/699449/23044)

Comment: А если скрипт запускается не из папки, в которой он лежит? Может, у автора вопроса с этим и проблема?

Comment: @AlexanderZonov: только одна команда (`python module1.py`) требует, чтобы модуль был текущей директории (автор пытается это в REPL запустить, вместо командной строки так что у автора множество проблем может быть)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь,всё понятно,но теперь интересует другой вопрос:как сделать,что бы импорт файла работал из нужной мне папки?Когда мой файл "module1.py" находится в директории с питоном,то всё работает,я создал в директории с питоном папку "myworks" и переместил файл туда,и теперь питон его не видит,хотя я добавил эту папку в Path

Comment: @Евгений это зависит от того что вы понимаете под "импорт файла" (запустить как скрипт или импортировать из другого скрипта -- если не знаете какая разница,  спрашивайте). Если как импортировать, то в ответе написано: посмотрите на `sys.path` список (если не понимаете как туда модуль поместить, спрашивайте). Не нужно пытаться модули рядом с python.exe класть. Изменение %PATH% переменной никак на sys.path не влияет (это совершенно независимый набор директорий). Если запустить как скрипт хотите, то отдельный вопрос задайте.

Comment: Чтобы с лексикой освоиться, посмотрите на связанные вопросы (понимать, что написано не обязательно, просто получите представление какие термины в каком контексте используются): [Как структурировать проект, чтобы запускать setup.py test из корневой папки проекта и `__main__.py` в субдериктории?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/623709/23044) [Помощь с включением файлов в проект](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/699449/23044)